# How to style xlsx files in node.js

Tags: javascript, excel, node.js, express, xlsx

I'm exporting a file generated by xlsx.js with my node.js express application server. I'd like to know how to put bold in first line, set auto width and (eventually) colour borders.
For example, the first line of the worksheet looks like:

```
var data = [[
        {value:"EXTREMELY LONG TITLE 1", bold: 1, autoWidth:true},
        {value:"TITLE2"},
        {value:"TITLE3"}
    ]];
```

My actual result is that these three cells are correctly printed and served. The attributes `bold` and `autoWidth` are ignored. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Not sure if there is an order of operations but in his test case it looks like he puts bold before the value. Also try single quotes...I'm just throwing ideas out there I've never used this before. Also sweet name.

Comment: @Thunda lol, yours too. Just tried that.. unfortunately without success. Ty anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of modules that can do it. But if you want to control the formatting of xlsx file, then I suggest you use this below code. Rows contain data in the form of JSON array.

```
var excel = require('node-excel-export');
var styles = {
    headerDark: {
        fill: {
            fgColor: {
                rgb: 'FF000000'
            }
        },
        font: {
            color: {
                rgb: 'FFFFFFFF'
            },
            sz: 14,
            bold: true,
            underline: true
        }
    },
    cellPink: {
        fill: {
            fgColor: {
                rgb: 'FFFFCCFF'
            }
        }
    },
    cellGreen: {
        fill: {
            fgColor: {
                rgb: 'FF00FF00'
            }
        }
    }
};

var specification = {
    "Col1": {
        "displayName": 'Col1Name',
        "headerStyle": styles.headerDark,
        "width": 250
    },
    "Col2": {
        "displayName": 'Col2Name',
        "headerStyle": styles.headerDark,
        "width": 215
    },
    "Col3": {
        displayName: 'Col3Name',
        headerStyle: styles.headerDark,
        width: 150
    }
}

var report = excel.buildExport(
    [{
        name: 'Report.xlsx',
        specification: specification,
        data: rows
    }]
);
```

This can then be sent either as response in the API :

```
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=Report.xlsx');
res.send(report);
```

Or as an attachment in email:

```
var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    host: "mail.yourmailman.com"
}));
transporter.sendMail({
    from: "abc.gmail.com",
    to: toAddr,
    subject: 'scheduled reporting',
    attachments: [{
        'filename': 'Report.xlsx',
        'content': new Buffer(report, 'base64')
    }]
}, function(error, success) {
    if (error) {
        logger.error('Error wile sending mail ', error);
        return;
    } else {
        logger.info('Mail sent.. ', success);
        return;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use xlsx, js-xlsx or node-xlsx. Create a formatted template and then insert the data into it.

[This may help](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/121)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I did not feel right quoting someone else's solution to the problem. That is pretty much the only template injection solution I have come across. I have been building my own solution to style xlsx using nodejs but it is far from release ready. [data4node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/data4node)